# Authentication with taffy

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, taffy

This is Something I am trying my head around but I am not sure why I am not able to grasp this thing. I am reading articles and wiki of taffy but somehow I am getting it. Like this:

`https://github.com/atuttle/Taffy/tree/master/examples/api_requireApiKey`

I am going down by the following approach:

I have created a table called as: `apikeys`, The table has just `3 columns`, `authid,apikey,authtoken`

now if i manually add some key and token, how should i pass it to my requests to call it from 3rd party application.

and eventually this is hardcoded, how can i change my `token` every few hours and if application detects that `token` has been changed or not matching, what should i call to `re-authenticate` it again with new token and keep it alive for  next few hours

If rather than solving, someone can point me to right direction, that will be great.

I tried reaching the **author** of `taffy`, but he is quite busy to answer the questions i have, everyone is pointing me to docs and docs does not tell me anything about this section.

Comment: Since you asked for help pointing you in the right direction (sorry, no knowledge of Taffy), there's a google groups forum that might better able to assist you.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/taffy-users